# Simplest way to enable Azure AD FS in a .NET application using Simplemembership

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, simplemembership

We have a .Net MVC web application using Simplemembership that one of our clients wants to use with Azure AD FS for authenticating his employees and collaborators. I'm looking for the simplest way to make that possible.

On principle, replacing Simplemembership is absolutely required for this task, isn't it?

As far as I understand, integrating Azure AD B2C would be a good way to upgrade our authentication process but would require us to introduce OWIN. Would that be a good solution or should I look at something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some confusion here around terms.

Do you mean ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services)? That's on-prem. There's no such thing as Azure ADFS.

B2C will work and you can federate that with [ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Your app. will have to use the [MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples) to authenticate.

And yes, you would replace Simplemembership.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, I mean ADFS. Can you confirm that there's no way around replacing SimpleMembership if you want to federate with ADFS?

Comment: To federate with ADFS, you have to have a client-side library that supports WS-Federation, SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect. Does SimpleMembership have that? (Not a SimpleMembership guru). Personally, from experience, go with MSAL.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Looks like SimpleMembership must go...